# Can ANY check for IS NOT NULL for an Array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, boolean, aggregate-functions

I have a query like this to group by one column and check if any of the records have data in a different column:

```
SELECT
  bar,
  MAX(CASE WHEN baz IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::BOOLEAN as baz_has_data
FROM
  foos
GROUP BY
  bar
```

I feel like that's a little bit cryptic, and thought using `ANY` and `ARRAY_AGG` would be clearer. Unfortunately I can't find any examples that include both an `IS NOT NULL` and an `ANY(ARRAY_AGG ...)`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a dedicated aggregate function for that: [**`bool_or()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

```
SELECT bar, bool_or(baz IS NOT NULL) AS baz_has_data
FROM   foos
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Yields `TRUE` if at least one row in the group has a non-null value.